# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onscreenclick' getting this error in python 3.9

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
turtle = Turtle()

def get_mouse_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_cor)

screen.mainloop()
```

Is it dependent on python version im using? my version is 3.9

I was expecting to get x,y cordinatees of mouse click

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to set the screen. Also, you don't actually need to set the `turtle = Turtle()` line, it works perfectly fine without.

```py
import turtle
  
def get_mouse_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)
  
# set screen
sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(400, 300)
  
turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_cor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set up the screen. So, like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
# You can remove this line below it works fine without it 
turtle = Turtle()
# THE PART YOU MISSED
screen = Screen()

def get_mouse_cor(x, y):
    print(x, y)
screen.onscreenclick(get_mouse_cor)

screen.mainloop()
```